# Select DISTINCT values with where clause returning more than one result on inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Code is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM tblWCS_Bulletins 
INNER JOIN tblWCS_BulletinComments ON tblWCS_BulletinComments.BulletinID = tblWCS_Bulletins.RowID 
WHERE VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') 
  AND CommentString LIKE ('%'   + @SearchString + '%')
   OR VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') 
  AND BulletinHeader LIKE ('%' +   @SearchString + '%') 
   OR VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') 
  AND BulletinContent LIKE ('%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

But this returns duplicates of the rows from the first table if more than one result is found in the second table. I want the result to only return one row from the first table, even if there is more than one row in the second joined table found.

Comment: What is surprising about the result?  The `select distinct` applies to all columns in the `select`.  You should provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, where do the columns come from?

Comment: If you want one result row per bulletin, but there exist, say, two comments for a bulletin: Which comment to show?

Comment: When mixing ANDs and ORs it is supposed to be good style to use parentheses, so as to make the intention crystal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query as below, This query will get the data only from first table with distinct values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblWCS_Bulletins.* 
FROM tblWCS_Bulletins 
INNER JOIN tblWCS_BulletinComments 
ON tblWCS_BulletinComments.BulletinID = tblWCS_Bulletins.RowID 
WHERE VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') AND CommentString LIKE ('%'   + @SearchString + '%')
OR VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') AND BulletinHeader LIKE ('%' +   @SearchString + '%') 
OR VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') AND BulletinContent LIKE ('%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do answers like this get accepted?  This version is not equivalent to the version in question, because it returns no columns from the second table.

Comment: In the question it has been clearly mentioned that only the row from first table should be returned as result.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want one row per `BulletinId`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT . . .,  -- list columns you want
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BulletinId ORDER BY BulletinId) as seqnum
      FROM tblWCS_Bulletins b INNER JOIN
           tblWCS_BulletinComments bc
           ON bc.BulletinID = b.RowID 
      WHERE (VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') AND CommentString LIKE ('%'   + @SearchString + '%')) OR
            (VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') AND BulletinHeader LIKE ('%' +   @SearchString + '%')) OR 
            (VisibleTo LIKE ('%@' + @UserID + '@%') AND BulletinContent LIKE ('%' + @SearchString + '%'))
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You should list the columns explicitly to avoid duplicate column names (not allowed in a subquery).

You can determine which row you want from the second table by adjusting the `ORDER BY` clause.